# return velocity template as ajax response

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, velocity

In my spring boot application I make ajax requests to modify some table. What I do now is send a json back to client side and than in js create new table data from it. 
I was wondering if it can be done otherwise: use model object to create html from velocity template (vm file) and then return somehow that html to be renderd in ajax callback function. 
Is there such a way?

Answer (score 0):

You can call ajax and render your entire page with velocity which support generating HTML, see [user guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html) for examples.